# Batch file to launch several programs

Tags: batch-file, exit

I have a Truecrypt (TC) container that gets Mounted at start up. Once mounted I need to launch a bunch of utility programs.

I tried a batch file but it stops at the first program and waits for it to close before going to the next line. I need to have all of them running and left running after the Cmd window has closed. Here's what I have, where "d:" is the TC mounted drive...

```
d:
cd \startstuff
d:\myclock.exe
d:\myappointments.exe
d:\mypasswords.exe
exit
```

I have the batch file as a shortcut on the desktop so I can double-click it after I have mounted the D: drive.

How can I get these all to run and close the Cmd window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
start /b "" "d:\myclock.exe"
...
```

Comment: Excellent thank you very much. Just one more question now, how to get the CMD window to close? I tried Exit, and Exit /B but it still stays open.